# Generated Doctrine models respect case, but generated Yaml does not

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, yaml, case

Just getting started with [Doctrine ORM for PHP](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) (v1.1.5) and ran into something unexpected.

I am generating models from the db (MySQL 4) using:

```
Doctrine::generateModelsFromDb($pathToModels);
```

Then generating YAML from the models using:

```
Doctrine::generateYamlFromModels($pathToSchema . '/schema.yml', $pathToModels);
```

In the generated models, the column names (as defined in `hasColumn()`) use the same case for the fields as in the db. All good.

But in the generated YAML, the column names are all lower-case, irrespective of the case in the model.

There do not seem to be any options available on the `generateYamlFromModels()` method that I could conceivably use to tweak this. Is there some other attribute I should be setting someplace, perhaps at connection-level, or at manager-level, etc? Might it be a bug?

Any ideas greatly appreciated. Thanks and cheers!

Comment: I had seen the question <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501501/doctrine-orm-models-not-respecting-case">Doctrine ORM: Models not respecting case</a>, but missed this bit in one of the answers:

<blockquote>As for field names, they can be mapped to camelCase using alias feature of YAML schema file (name: user_id as userId).</blockquote>

So, is that all there is? No way to get case-respect on Yaml generation, but I can manually tweak the YAML using aliasing?

Comment: Jeez, what is it about publicly posting a question that makes the answers just pop right out? The same answer as above (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501501/doctrine-orm-models-not-respecting-case/1620387#1620387) notes "Moreover, you can automate field aliasing by developing custom task for Doctrine.". I'll research more and maybe a follow-up there if necessary. Sorry. [Please don't downvote me. I'm right on the edge of comment privileges.]

Comment: It appears that Doctrine_Table::setColumn() sets the column name to lower case is it does not see an alias in there.

Comment: an other alternative is to generate models from DB and then yaml from models. This one keeps the right casing.

Comment: @Dmitri Baltas: This seems to be the best workaround. So, if you move this to an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Why are you using 1.15? There are mutch newer versions out there.

Comment: @edem: The original question dates back to 2009. Can't remember, but that was probably current at the time.

Comment: @Dmitris Baltas: Just a reminder that if you move your comment into an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 2):

It seems this is a bug. I say that because [YAML is case sensitive](http://ess.khhq.net/wiki/YAML_Tutorial), and Doctrine's `generateYAMLFromModels()` [is documented to be case sensitive](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CFgQFjAG&url=http://doctrine-loader.googlecode.com/files/doctrine-orm-manual-1-2-en.pdf&rct=j&q=Doctrine%3a%3agenerateYamlFromModels%20case%20sensitive&ei=5EBJTs_GA6vPiALK3Mm2DA&usg=AFQjCNGAMJuEhqVH6hoxgstiAgagzZLgtw&cad=rja). I did find a [case sensitivity bug](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-191) that was in 2.0 beta. Maybe this is the bug that affected your program. Barring anything else, though, it looks like Dimitris Baltas' comment seems to be the the workaround of choice:

> an other alternative is to generate models from DB and then yaml from models. This one keeps the right casing.

Happy Hunting :)